# How to get JQGrid date column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

In have a date column in my JQgrid and I have added a date picker to fetch the date.
Now, I want to get the fetched date value when I click the save button. For that I have added the following code to get the values but its not working, it's getting undefined.

```
{ name: 'DD', index: 'DD', width: (pageWidth*(9/100)), editable: true ,editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); } } },
```

Getting this column value on of my function like this,

```
function myFun() {
    var findSubGrid = $('#myGrid') ;
    var myDate=  $('text#'+'DD').val() 
    // Getting Error here is undefined.    
}
```

How do I get selected the date inside my function ?